# How to add button delete of element Datagridview in webform

Tags: asp.net, webforms

```
 private void LayThongTinHoSo(string sMaDDK)
    {
        try
        {
            DataTable dt = new ReportClass().GetImageList_HOSO_THICONG(sMaDDK);

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                string sFilePath = ResolveUrl("~/" + row["FILENAME"]);
                row["PATH"] = "<img src='" + sFilePath + "' width='400' '" + "' border='0' />";
               
            }

            grdDanhSachHoSo.DataSource = dt;
            grdDanhSachHoSo.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

I have function to list of image , how to add button delete in code in "for each" after element image show ?

[the image describe about the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jP3PM.png)

Comment: Recommendation: Don't use GridView to do this. Use dynamic HTML+Javascript+Ajax to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recommendation: Don't use GridView to do this. Use dynamic HTML+Javascript+Ajax to do this.

But if you really want to do this in GridView, here is one of the way that you can do:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv1" runat="server" OnRowDeleting="gv1_RowDeleting">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" />
        <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="PATH" HeaderText="Img"></asp:ImageField>
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="true" DeleteText="Delete" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

At the code behind:

```
protected void gv1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    // do delete
}
```